# Первоначальное значение слова "шарага"

Tags: этимология

Какое первоначальное значение у слова "шарага"? Ответы про ФЗУ, ШРМ, ГПТУ и особые учреждения НКВД не принимаются, ибо в камере Суздальской секретной тюрьмы у заключённого отца Конона хранилась "шарага" (по описи 19 века). http://lubovbezusl.ru/publ/istorija/muzei_vladimirskoj_oblasti/p/51-1-0-1056

Comment: Я подозреваю, что "шарага" XIX века может быть случайным совпадением, а то и неверным прочтением источника. Больно уж не к месту там, нет ничего подходящего в известных современных значениях.

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Почти уверен, что нашел правильное понимание того, что было в камере..

Comment: Вряд ли это "очепятка". Я смотрел фильм "Суздаль- город музей" в нём ведущая как раз читает эту опись. При слове "шарага" мне показалось, что я ослышался - но, нет нашёл ссылку в инете с шарагой в Суздале.

Comment: Так ведущая, вероятно, и читала тот же современный текст.  Не оригинал же с ятями она в руках держала? Точно так же солонку они называют то солянкой, то вообще солнякой... Но это ерунда, я только высказывал предположение, потом нашел вполне, имхо, разумное объяснение, не требующее предположения об ошибке (см. текст вопроса).

Comment: Другой вопрос, связана ли эта историческая шарага с современной. И тут я по-прежнему считаю, что это случайное совпадение. Значений у "шарага" вообще много, так что привязывать можно у чему угодно.

Answer (score 2):

**Шаражка** - подставка для лучины в виде вилки с зубцами.
*Шарагу вырезают, в нее лучину вкалывают* (Мошков, Алферово).
[**шаражка**](https://books.google.ee/books?redir_esc=y&hl=et&id=288JAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0)

**Шарага**
*Шаражка скована железная, служила затыкать лучину, эту шаражку хоть вилка назови* (Ордын., Пушкари).
[**шарага**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=0MkCAAAAMAAJ&q=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0&dq=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0&hl=et&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

**Шарага, шаражка** - это "держатель" для лучины: деревянный или железный (кованый).
Думаю, что приспособление совсем небольшое; светец все-таки покрупнее.

Comment: но какая лучина в XIX веке - да еще в камере? К тому же - диалектное сибирское слово в суздальском казенном доме.

Comment: А что должно было быть в камере - канделябр?.. "В старой восточнославянской деревне лесной и лесостепной полос до середины, а местами и до конца XIX в. почти единственным видом освещения жилища...служила лучина. В захолустных местностях и особенно в бедняцких жилищах этот способ освещения удерживался до Октябрьской революции".  СТАРООБРЯДЧЕСКИЙ епископ Конон - с 1859 по 1881 гг. – секретный арестант Суздальской монастырской тюрьмы. Почему же он не мог пользоваться лучиной? Вполне возможно, что список вещей мог составлять уроженец Сибири, назвав светец шарагой.

Comment: *А что должно было быть в камере* свеча и подсвечник. И он там упоминается в другом месте. Или вообще ничего. Освещение лучинами в тюрьмах - полнейший нонсенс. Кстати, вы представляете "технологию"? Как разжигать, как гасить? Под ней должна бочка с водой стоять. Иначе пожар неизбежен.

Comment: *СТАРООБРЯДЧЕСКИЙ епископ Конон* - он не бедный человек был, между прочим. Епископ.

Comment: Его богатство - не факт, стяжательство - не в традициях староверов, да и вообще в этом течении отношение лицам с духовным саном иное. См беспоповцы.

Comment: В камере должен быть осветительный прибор (сан заключённого и наличие книг при коротком зимнем световом дне). Вряд ли для этого выделялись средства на дорогие свечи (узники сидели без суда, пожизненно). То, что считается сибирскими диалектами - может быть на самом деле быть остатками старославянской речи, расселение русскоязычного населения за Урал проходило задолго до Ермака. Вспоминаем историю города Мангазея.

Comment: @Дмитрий Наличие в камере кувшина с водой и таза, мне кажется, поддерживают мою версию. Бочка тут совсем необязательна.

Comment: Я склоняюсь к тому (на основе комментариев), что шарага - это штаив, тенога, не совсем устойчивая опора, возможно первоначально коряга, корневище. И разницы по назначению: для одежды (вешалка) или для лучины я не вижу. Неологизм "шарага" и "шаражкина контора" в принципе объединяется понятием ненадёжный.

Comment: Эх-эх!.. Мы тут копья ломаем, а другие сайты нашу информацию вовсю используют — как свою. (https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=1104)  И обидно (ссылок-то не дают!), и приятно (значит, не зря, не просто так "ползаем", ищем, спорим!) — одновременно.

Answer (score 1):

Современное значение "шарага" - от "шарашка", а она в свою очередь от разговорного и диалектного глагола "шарашить" - бить, ударять с громким шумом. Насколько понимаю, во второй четверти XX века, когда шарашками стали называть разные закрытые учреждения (а через них и разного рода особую работу, не только в "ящиках", отхожий промысел) слово "шарашить" в исходном значении было еще на слуху и вполне могло послужить основой для меткого названия подобных структур. Переход *шарашка < шпрага* не должен удивлять, он реализует вполне проуктивные фонетические и грамматические модели.

Того же происхождения, видимо и упоминаемое у Даля диалектное значение.

ШАРАГА? об. тоб. кривляка, ломака, корчила, дергун.
http://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=43366

В значениях подходящем под описание монашеской кельи не встречалось. 
Версия про гребень была бы вполне правдоподобной, но откуда там "ага"? От шарить было бы в лучшем случае "шарга". Шарага должна бы быть от шарашить, а у него нет подходящих значений. Можно подумать про какую-то трещотку, но  что она в келье делает-то?

(+++++++++++++++++)

Посмотрел еще по источникам. Дело еще более запутывается. 
Далеко не все согласны с общим происхождением шараги и шарашки - и нельзя сходу сказать, что доводы противников несостоятельны. 
Но главное то, что у "шарашить(ся)" есть еще несколько значений. И проследить возможность порождения "шараги" от каждого из них не представляется возможным. Нужно именно знатока монашеского и тюремного быта. По ощущениям - в описи не хватает чего-то из носильного, повседневной одежды какой-то. Кафтана, может быть.

///=============================

Я нашел!

> шарага .... szaragi польск. - "вешалка (стоячая)"

http://andrej102.ru/estest/sm/fgr/fgr0511.htm

В сходных значениях - трехногая подставка, тренога - фиксируется и другими словарями.

Вот ***вешалка*** - да еще в списке сразу перед шлафроком (теплым халатом) - вполне возможно.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что слова шарошка (шарошить) и шарага (шаражка) совершенно разного происхождения. Моя версия слова шарошка - инструмент с зазубринами в иконописи для финишной обработки доски для иконы: шара (краска), шародейство (расписание красками), шарчий (живописец, иконописец)

Comment: А шарага (если считать её треногой, вешалкой или держателем) возможно в родстве со словом "на раскоряку" (на расшорагу?)

Comment: @Morkovkin Сибирский диалект Вас смущает... Но по-Вашему - получается, что польский язык в Суздале был распространен повсеместно.

Comment: Сибирский диалект меня как раз не смущает, наоборот словообразование "сибирского диалекта" не тюркского происхождения с большой долей вероятности нужно искать в старославянском. Я уже писал, что современная популярная историография не совсем верно описывает начало заселения Сибири русскоязычным населением.

Comment: Вряд ли в конкретной описи шарагой названа вешалка ибо в перечне вещей камеры священника Фёдора Померанцева (там же) указана вешалка словом "вешалка". Но ваша находка польского термина СТОЯЧЕЙ вешалки много поясняет.

Comment: @Дмитрий, ну да, вешалка - именно вешалка, а "шарага" - это особый тип, "тренога". Что-то же могло было быть подобное и этого, коли у другого заключенного. Но у о. Конона вешалка не фигурирует. А куда он свой шлафрок вешал?

Comment: отец Конон личность выдающаяся, как выяснилось, отличался аскетизмом (после пострига прожил 5 лет отшельником в пещере), за 22 года заключения его так и не склонили к единоверию. Такой человек вряд ли будет остро нуждаться в вешалке, а вот отсутствие возможности писать его точно огорчило бы. В заключении он писал комментарии к библейским книгам ( аж 2 стола в камере) и даже по разрешению выезжал в московскую библиотеку.

Comment: Да и слово "шарага" на столько древнее, что даже Даль "толкует" слово неологизмом. Согласитесь, что приспособление для лучины появилось много раньше стоячей вешалки. Хотя не факт, что и это не древний "неологизм". Помогли бы однокоренные слова, но их что-то не видно...

Answer (score 1):

"Шарага"архиепископа - не имеет отношения к названию тюремной  шараги НКВД (она от "шарашкиной конторы", как разъясняется в "Архипелаге ГУЛаг").

Шарага отца Конона - от слова "шарак"- сермяжка - грубая одежда из серого некрашеного сукна. Шлафрок ватный, тёплый, а шарага - простой кафтан, это из белорусского языка, среди донского казачества слово известное, он же казаком был до монашества.

Comment: Серый (именно серый шар-) кафтан как верхняя одежда для монаха (сана его не лишали) возможен теоретически, но вряд ли писец использовал бы этот белорусский термин в отношении одежды духовного лица. Только если сам писец был белорусам или казаком. Замена "г" в "к" может произойти легко, но буква "а" на конце намекает на ж.р. предмета, а кафтан точно не ж.р.

Comment: Это не белорусский термин, это диалект в бел.яз., Русские крестьяне рабочую одежду называли сермягой, а   казаки шарагой, что созвучно с шараком белорусов,  потом слово шарага стало жаргонным словом. Сам шарак - от "шара"-выварки от чая ( как и  шарабара) - хлам, плохие пожитки, одежонка и утварь. Потому и шарага - плохая одежонка.
Шара - http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/376634/%D0%A8%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%90

Comment: Так что можно сказать, что первоначальное значение слова "шарага" - хлам, одежонка, то, что даётся даром. От него можно вывести и значение тюремной "шарашкиной конторы" - они тоже работали даром, и современного сленга - всякие ПТУ - то, где плохо, задарма.

Comment: Кстати, в списке стоит рядом со шлафроком - два вида одежды рядом.

Comment: Русские крестьяне рабочую одежду называли сермягой, а казаки шарагой - это версия или есть источник? Шарак - не только серый кафтан, но и заяц (вероятно русак, серый). А слов с корнем шар- (краска, цвет) множество как устаревших, так и современных: шарОвая краска на флоте, кличка собак Шарик (Серый).

Comment: Не слышал, что бы дармовые вещи назывались шарагой. "Получить на шару (но не на шарагу)" - выражение известное. Выражение вероятно произошло от обычая раздавать-поздравлять по праздникам крашеные (шарОвые) яйца. ШорОвое заговенье, яблочный спас, морковкино заговенье и прочие праздники всё ещё на слуху. Те опять же шара - корень краска.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, шарага – от слова шарить (искать). Пренебрежительно о частом гребне (расческе), - средстве борьбы с педикулезом.

Comment: Можете указать источник?

Comment: Никак нет. Это не более, чем догадка.

Comment: Не очень убедительная версия: перечень вещей - документ официальный для надзирателей, вряд ли в нём могла использоваться сниженная лексика. Да и состав списка несколько иной: мебель, посуда, одежда, книги, предметы культа.

Comment: И еще: ...кружка, солонка, ...рукомойник с тазом... Заметим, что последнее - предметы гигиены, но не культа.

Comment: В другом месте упоминается "солняка". Тоже совершенно непонятно. Похоже не на сниженную лексику, но на какой-то профессиональный жаргон.

Comment: Есть и короче слово: шара, шар с исходным значением — краска, цвет, красная краска, сурик; шарий — живописец. Не менее правдоподобно (со снижением): шарага = малярка.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, шарага (шараги) - первоначально обозначали оборонительные деревянные рогатки (прадедушка противотанкового ежа).
Найдены следующие слова: шараги (укр) - стоячая вешалка, шаражка - подставка для лучины в виде вилки с зубцами, szaragi (польск) - вешалка стоячая.
Но сами поляки считают это слово немецким https://translate.google.ru/translate?hl=ru&sl=pl&u=http://portalwiedzy.onet.pl/105823,,,,szaragi,haslo.html&prev=search
schräg (нем) - косой, поперечный, наклонный, вкось
Schrägen - козлы, деревянные козлы (НЕМЕЦКО-РУССКИЙ КОЖЕВЕННЫЙ ХИМИКО- ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ)
Почему оборонительные рогатки: в Беларусии имеется 3 населённых пункта с названием Шараги. Иного обяснения, как место ограждённое "противотанковыми ежами" не вижу. Аналогия - слово город (место ограждённое сплошным забором, стеной).
Благодарю всех принявших участие в обсуждении.

Comment: schrägstrich - косая черта, слэш "/" по немецки. Если коммерческий договор оформлен с косой чертой у подписи, он может быть признан не действительным.  Schrägstrich Kontor - шаражкина контора?

Answer (score 0):

В месопотамских текстах им нередко также соответствует шумерская лолограмма «SA.GAZ», См. картинку. Слово было "шараша", но прошло через греческий фильтр (греки не выговаривали звук "ш", да и с "р" были у них проблемы) и стало читаться как сагаз. В переводе с шумерско-аккадско-финикийского языка значит "организация, объединение, компания,войско, банда". В истории отмечено присутствие шараг (они же "хабиру", "хэврэ", "хэбрэ" в ркаях в которые потом мигрировали слОвяне - бассейны рек Волга, Днепр, Дон, Днестр. Так слово (вначале с тем же смыслом) и перекочевало в славянские языки. Например - От этого сохранилось в русском "шайка". А в обиходе "шарашка" - тоже  ведь про организацию.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]